# SQL find name of worker with maximum average score

Tags: sql, oracle, average, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to display the name of the worker(s) with the largest average marks.
My first table is the worker table and stores the worker_id and worker_name. The second table is the test table and stores the worker_id of who took the test, the test_id, and the marks.

My goal is to be able to print the name of the worker who has the highest average marks across all tests. This is what I have so far:

```
    select max(avg_mark) as max_avg
    from (
        select worker_name, avg(mark) as avg_mark
        from worker join test worker.worker_id = test.worker_id
        group by worker_name
        order by avg(mark) desc);
```

However, this only returns the VALUE of the maximum average mark and not the name(s) of the worker(s) who have that average. If I add `worker_name` to the first select statement and also add a group by `worker_name` at the bottom then all the workers are returned with their averages!

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Please show table definitions, sample data, and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. The idea is to select the worker who's average matches the max found in a separate query. Here is an example:

```
select master.worker_name, mx.max_mark
from
(select worker_name, avg(mark) as avg_mark
 from worker
 inner join test on worker.worker_id = test.worker_id
 group by worker_name) master
inner join
(select max(mark) as max_mark
 from test) mx
on master.avg_mark = mx.max_mark
```

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use a CTE and then query it using the max window function.

```
with cte as
(
    select worker_name, avg(mark) as avg_mark
    from worker join test worker.worker_id = test.worker_id
    group by worker_name
)
select t.*
from
(
    select worker_name, avg_mark, max(avg_mark) over (partition by worker_name) max_mark
    from cte
) t
where t.avg_mark = t.max_mark
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select      min(worker_name) keep (dense_rank last order by avg(mark))
from        worker join test worker.worker_id = test.worker_id
group by    worker_name
;
```

Answer (score -1):

So add worker_name,  order by Max avg descending. Then limit result to 1.